# Is there a way to upload to a shared Sharepoint folder other than the web app? It's painfully slow

Tags: sharepoint-online

For a client I am required to upload files to a shared Sharpoint / OneDrive folder, which is accessed via a link to [client subdomain].sharepoint.com/

The issue is that the uploads seem to be capped at around 200KB/s, whilst uploads to other services such as Google Drive or Speedtest.net hit around 2300KB/s.

This is on Firefox and Chrome on macOS

So is there an alternative way to upload to a shared folder? I tried the OneDrive app, but it doesn't seem to have a way to access a shared folder.

Comment: How are you performing the upload?  
Can you provide a screenshot?  Are you using ‘Explorer View’ to perform the upload?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some migration tools to migrate large files, such as sharepoint migration tool(SPMT). But per my research, SPMT doesn't support macOS. You could use some other third-party migration tools.

This article is an overview about migrating your content to Microsoft 365: [Migrate to Microsoft 365](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/migrate-to-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of migration tools (e.g. https://directory.collab365.com/office365-sharepoint/best-sharepoint-migration-tools/) but very few support macOS.

One alternative is to use a browser-based tool that supports multiple browsers on macOS. You should get better performance than the web app.

Paul | SLIM Applications